# Подмена HTTP-кода ответа Nginx

Tags: nginx, http, rewrite

Возможно ли в Nginx подменить http код ответа на 200, сохранив и отдав клиенту исходное тело ответа (т.е. error_page скорее всего не вариант)?

Comment: Вы про proxy_pass/fastcgi_pass? А зачем?

Comment: Есть некий абстрактный сервис отдающий json есть необходимость кешировать его ответы с кодом 200 и не кешировать 4** и 5** ответы. С сервисом работает некий веб-гуй на JS, который валится, если к нему приходит ответ с кодом отличным от 200.

Comment: И нельзя починить веб?

Comment: Можно, переписав Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer и установив такую пропатченую версию всем пользователям :) В ином случае к сожалению никак.

Comment: Не понял. Браузеры отлично работают с любым кодом ответа. Проблемы обычно в кривизне рук авторов js-кода.

Comment: Рабтают, только вот как только приходит в запросе json'а код отличный от 200 - дальше js-код не выполняется :(